# Converting CSV with Comma Space Comma to float

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working in python using pandas and ultimately wanting to run a random forest. Python bugs out because I can't get this numeric column with spaces as nulls to be converted to a float. I tried fillna with zero and astype(float) but no success. Thanks all!

```
    sm['PopHalfMile']
Out[64]:

0      2072
1      4392
2      2986
3          
4          
       ... 
281    3350
282    1481
283     607
284    4708
285    4237
Name: PopHalfMile, Length: 286, dtype: object
In [65]:

sm['PopHalfMile'].fillna(value=0)
Out[65]:

0      2072
1      4392
2      2986
3          
4          
       ... 
281    3350
282    1481
283     607
284    4708
285    4237
Name: PopHalfMile, Length: 286, dtype: object

So i looked at the csv file in notepad and their is a space where the data is null. ...comma space comma.

6, ,2103,



This is causing  me to get this error after trying to convert the field to a float.

sm["PopHalfMile"] = sm.PopHalfMile.astype(float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: do you have integers or floats in the column?

Comment: You could do a find and replace in your csv. So look for ", ," and replace it with ",," or ",0,"

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace() instead of fillna(), because the values you are trying to replace are not nulls apparently; they are spaces?

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df.replace(" ", 0)
```

Comment: this wouldn't work because the column would still have strings and would still be an object.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV is comma delimited and your reading in your dataframe as such I'd use regex to extact all numeric values from your column then cast it to a float using the `astype` method

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['15,', ',15.5,', np.nan, ',2017,']})
print(df)
    A
0   15,
1  ,15.5,
2   NaN
3  ,2017,
```

#### We can then leverage a regular expression to extract all numbers inc floats.

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'([\d\.\d]+)').fillna(0).astype(float)
       A       B
0     15,    15.0
1  ,15.5,    15.5
2     NaN     0.0
3  ,2017,  2017.0
```

#### Checking the `dtypes`

```
print(df.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
dtype: object
```